# Calculating product of a rolling groupby while respecting datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, with ID being a unique identifier, date being monthly observations and 1+return being the return for the given month of date.

```
ID,   date,      1+return
1   31-01-2007     1.1           
1   31-02-2007     1.1           
1   31-03-2007     1.1
2   31-01-2007     1.2           
2   31-02-2007     1.2           
2   31-07-2007     1.2
```

I want to create a column in the dataframe with the cumulative return for each ID. The cumulative return have to meet these criteria:

1) It should only get computed in so far that there are 3 observations available, otherwise return nan.

2) It should only compute it for 3 observations and then roll forward

3) It should only compute returns for the same ID. Hence, Groupby

4) It should only compute the return if the 3 observations are spread out by 3 months. Note, that for ID (2) the last date entry skips several months.

I have written the following code:

```
df['cumret'] = df.sort_values(by='date').groupby('id') 
               ['1+return'].rolling(3,min_periods=3).apply(lambda x: 
               x.prod()).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

This gives the following output:

```
ID,   date,      1+return   cumret
1   31-01-2007     1.1        NA     
1   31-02-2007     1.1        NA 
1   31-03-2007     1.1       1.331
2   31-01-2007     1.2        NA
2   31-02-2007     1.2        NA
2   31-07-2007     1.2        1.728
```

I want this output instead:

```
ID,   date,      1+return   cumret
1   31-01-2007     1.1        NA     
1   31-02-2007     1.1        NA 
1   31-03-2007     1.1       1.331
2   31-01-2007     1.2        NA
2   31-02-2007     1.2        NA
2   31-07-2007     1.2        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Try resampling the data to monthly frequency and then run the same command.

```
df['cumret'] = df.resample('M').asfreq().groupby('id') 
           ['1+return'].rolling(3,min_periods=3).apply(lambda x: 
           x.prod()).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

Comment: I can't get this to work on a more complex dataframe. This seems like a quick fix rather than an actual fix?